# Odoo quotation confirmation error

Tags: python, odoo

I've got an **Odoo 8.0** application running on an Ubuntu 15.04, which hosted on a Microsoft Azure Virtual Machine.

I'd like to create a quotation on the administration surface. The creation went fine. But if I try to confirm (or send by email) the quotation, I get an **Odoo Server Error**.

Here's its **traceback**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 537, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 574, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 310, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/service/model.py", line 113, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 307, in checked_call
    return self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 803, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 403, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 944, in call_kw
    return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 936, in _call_kw
    return getattr(request.registry.get(model), method)(request.cr, request.uid, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/models.py", line 5160, in search_read
    result = self.read(cr, uid, record_ids, fields, context=read_ctx)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/models.py", line 3142, in read
    result = BaseModel.read(records, fields, load=load)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 239, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/models.py", line 3177, in read
    self._read_from_database(stored, inherited)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 239, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/models.py", line 3356, in _read_from_database
    res2 = self._columns[f].get(cr, self._model, ids, f, user, context=context, values=result)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/osv/fields.py", line 1467, in get
    result = self._fnct(obj, cr, uid, ids, name, self._arg, context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/portal_sale/portal_sale.py", line 31, in <lambda>
    _payment_block_proxy = lambda self, *a, **kw: self._portal_payment_block(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/portal_sale/portal_sale.py", line 44, in _portal_payment_block
    partner_id=this.partner_id.id, company_id=this.company_id.id, context=context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/payment/models/payment_acquirer.py", line 299, in render_payment_block
    context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/payment/models/payment_acquirer.py", line 271, in render
    return self.pool['ir.ui.view'].render(cr, uid, acquirer.view_template_id.xml_id, qweb_context, engine='ir.qweb', context=context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/website/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 181, in render
    return super(view, self).render(cr, uid, id_or_xml_id, values=values, engine=engine, context=context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 1026, in render
    return self.pool[engine].render(cr, uid, id_or_xml_id, qcontext, loader=loader, context=context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 262, in render
    return self.render_node(self.get_template(id_or_xml_id, qwebcontext), qwebcontext)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 199, in get_template
    raise QWebTemplateNotFound("Template %r not found" % name, template=origin_template)
QWebTemplateNotFound: Template u'account_voucher.view_voucher_filter' not found
```

Can anyone help how can I fix this?

Thanks in advance for any replies

Comment: Which part of my code? (i've got a package edition installed)

Answer (score 0):

1. It seems like you have not installed the "account_voucher" module,because of which it is not able to fetch the template present in that module.
   Go to Settings --> Local Modules and Install account_voucher module.
2. Check whether you have added "account_voucher" module under 'depends' in **openerp**.py file.
3. Check the existence of "view_voucher_filter" in "account_voucher" module.